# Perl read line and the next one

Tags: regex, xml, perl, parsing

I need to make a parse to an XML file. I need to take time codes (Beginning and ending) and the sentence related to this times.

The XML file is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Trans SYSTEM "trans-14.dtd">
<Trans scribe="jj" audio_filename="01" version="1" version_date="150211">
 <Episode>
  <Section type="report" startTime="0" endTime="50.28281021118164">
   <Turn startTime="0" endTime="50.28281021118164">
    <Sync time="0"/>

    <Sync time="1.195"/>
    Something
    <Sync time="2.654"/>
    Something 2
    <Sync time="4.356"/>
    Something 3
    <Sync time="9.321"/>
    Something 4
    <Sync time="22.171"/>
    Something 5
    <Sync time="28.351"/>
    Something 6
    <Sync time="35.708"/>
    Something 7
    <Sync time="43.04"/>
    Something 8
   </Turn>
  </Section>
</Episode>
```

I have tried this in Perl, but is not working well:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -nw
next if ! /<Sync/;
$stime = "";
$sentence = "";
$etime = "";

$stime = $1 if (/Sync time="([0-9]+\.[0-9]*)"/);
$sentence = <>;
chomp($sentence);

if ($stime eq ''){ $stime = 0;}

print "$stime  $sentence\n";
__END__
```

Because my desired output format would be:

```
0  1.195
1.195 2.654 Something
2.654 4.356 Something 2
4.356 9.321 Something 3
9.321 22.171 Something 4
22.171 28.351 Something 5
28.351 35.708 Something 6
35.708 43.04 Something 7
43.04 endTime Something 8
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Don't do it this way - an XML parser is what you want for this job.

Answer (score 2):

So firstly - it's really bad juju to do line oriented parsing of XML. XML is a data format, and the structure is quite important - such that there's a few things there where you can restructure it in perfectly valid ways, and it'll break.

So your starter for 10:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( 'sample.xml' );

my $previous_sync = 0; 
foreach my $sync ( $twig -> get_xpath('Episode/Section/Turn/Sync') ) {
   my $sync_time =  $sync -> att('time');
   print "$previous_sync $sync_time ", $sync->text,"\n";
   $previous_sync = $sync_time;
}
print "$previous_sync ", $twig -> get_xpath('Episode/Section',0) -> att('endTime'),"\n";
```

Now, I'm having a slight problem in that your 'Somethings' there aren't actually associated with the respective 'sync' elements. They're 'text content' of the parent `Turn`. (The `Sync` elements are unary tags).

But hopefully this illustrates a better way of parsing XML?

Edit: Update to work with your text as is.
NB: I've had to modify your XML to include `</Trans>` as the last line, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Trans SYSTEM "trans-14.dtd">
<Trans scribe="jj" audio_filename="01" version="1" version_date="150211">
 <Episode>
  <Section type="report" startTime="0" endTime="50.28281021118164">
   <Turn startTime="0" endTime="50.28281021118164">
    <Sync time="0"/>

    <Sync time="1.195"/>
    Something
    <Sync time="2.654"/>
    Something 2
    <Sync time="4.356"/>
    Something 3
    <Sync time="9.321"/>
    Something 4
    <Sync time="22.171"/>
    Something 5
    <Sync time="28.351"/>
    Something 6
    <Sync time="35.708"/>
    Something 7
    <Sync time="43.04"/>
    Something 8
   </Turn>
  </Section>
</Episode>
</Trans>
```

So if that still look ok, and you aren't actually trying to work with broken XML, this gives the desired output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $previous_sync;

sub handle_sync {
    my ( $twig, $sync ) = @_;
    my $sync_time = $sync->att('time');
    if ( not defined $previous_sync ) {
        $previous_sync = $sync_time;
        return;
    }
    print "$previous_sync $sync_time ";
    $previous_sync = $sync_time;
    my (@sync_text) = split( "\n", $sync->parent->text );
    pop(@sync_text);    #discard blank line.
    my $line = pop(@sync_text);
    if ( defined $line ) {
        $line =~ s/^\s+//g;
        print $line;
    }
    print "\n";
}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { 'Sync' => \&handle_sync } )
    ->parsefile('sample.xml');
print "$previous_sync ",
    $twig->get_xpath( 'Episode/Section', 0 )->att('endTime'), " ";

my @sync_text =
    split( "\n", $twig->get_xpath( 'Episode/Section/Turn', 0 )->text );
my $line = $sync_text[-2];
$line =~ s/^\s+//g;
print $line, "\n";
```

It's a bit of a fudge, because the 'text' in there is part of the `Turn` element - so I'm taking a 'print the last (full) line' approach. This seems to work, but probably won't if you've multi-lines in there.

Comment: Thank you Sobrique, but I'm realy bad with Ubuntu and I can't install XML::Twig for Perl...

Comment: @Sergi: Type `cpan` on terminal, then `install XML::Twig`

Comment: I think Ubuntu probably has a pre-built package too. `libxml-twig-perl` which you could install with `sudo apt-get install libxml-twig-perl` (I think!)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with those above, that you should try to stick with an XML library.  But using your exact example, and assuming the data you are working on will not change.  This code will do what you want.  However, if any format of your message is changed, this code will need work.  You can decide if this is good enough to suit your needs.

```
open(my $newfh, '<', 'testXML.xml') or die "Could Not Open File";
# You will need variables from previous loop iterations
my $lastsyncTime = "";
my $lastSomething = "";
while(my $line = <$newfh>){

    # Regex that stores the Sync Time in $1
    if($line =~ m/Sync\stime\s*=\s*"(\d+.?\d*)"/){
        my $syncTime = $1;
        # Check if there was a previous sync time
        if($lastsyncTime != ""){
            print "$lastsyncTime $syncTime $lastSomething\n";
        }
        $lastsyncTime = $syncTime;
    }
    # We didnt find a sync time.  Must be a data line
    else{
        # Check that our data isnt an end tag
        if($line !~ m/<\/.*>/){
            # Remove end of line
            chomp $line;
            # Remove any whitespace at the beginning of the line
            $line =~ s/^\s+//;
            $lastSomething = $line;
        }
    }
}
print "$lastsyncTime endTime $lastSomething\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML):

```
open sample.xml ;
for //Sync
    echo @time normalize-space(following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]) ;
```